# How can I check the section type if I have the symbol of the section and its index? (in c language)

Tags: c, elf

I want to make sure that if I found a global symbol, and it's in a shared object, then put in err_value -4.
I'm not sure what should be my if statement in the place in the code I marked. if the symbol is not in a shared object then it should enter inside the if part.

```
Elf64_Shdr* section_h_arr = (Elf64_Shdr*)((char*)elf + elf_header->e_shoff);
Elf64_Shdr sh_str_section = section_h_arr[elf_header->e_shstrndx];

char *sh_str_tbl = (char*)elf + sh_str_section.sh_offset;
Elf64_Half sections_amount = elf_header->e_shnum;

Elf64_Sym *symtab;
char *strtab;
int symbols_amount = 0;
char* section_name;

for(int i = 0; i < sections_amount; i++) {
    section_name = sh_str_tbl + section_h_arr[i].sh_name;
    if(!strcmp(".symtab", section_name) || section_h_arr[i].sh_type == 2){
        symtab = (Elf64_Sym*)((char*)elf + section_h_arr[i].sh_offset);
        symbols_amount = section_h_arr[i].sh_size / section_h_arr[i].sh_entsize;
    }
    else if(!strcmp(".strtab", section_name) || section_h_arr[i].sh_type == 3){
        if((char*)elf + section_h_arr[i].sh_offset != sh_str_tbl)
            strtab = ((char*)elf + section_h_arr[i].sh_offset);
    }
}
char* curr_symbol_name;


for(int i = 0; i < symbols_amount; i++){
    curr_symbol_name = strtab + symtab[i].st_name;
    if(!strcmp(symbol_name, curr_symbol_name)) {
        if(ELF64_ST_BIND(symtab[i].st_info) == STB_GLOBAL) {
            close(elf_fd);
            *error_val=1;
            if (///////////////////////////////// )
            {
                return symtab[i].st_value;
            }
            *error_val=-4;
            return 0; }
```

My first try was "section_h_arr[symtab[i].st_shndx].sh_type!=ET_DYN" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement you want is:

```
if (elf_header->e_type == ET_DYN) ...
```

> My first try was `section_h_arr[symtab[i].st_shndx].sh_type!=ET_DYN` but it doesn't work

That statement makes no sense -- it only makes sense to compare `sh_type` with `SHT_...` constants.

Also, the `ET_DYN` or `ET_EXEC` is a property of the entire `ELF` image, and not of any section within it.